# Prove the inequality: $ | 1 - K | < 1 $

Tags: inequality

Given

\begin{gather*} 
Q \geq 0 \\
R > 0 \\
P > 0 \\
QR - S^2 > 0 \\
P = \frac{-(2S - Q) + \sqrt{(2S-Q)^2+4(QR-S^2)}}{2} \\
K = \frac{S+P}{R+P}
\end{gather*}
prove 
$$
|1-K|<1.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $|1-K|<1$ iff $|R-S|<R+P$. Since $P>Q/2-S$, it suffices to show that $|R-S|\le R+Q/2-S.$
If $R\ge S$ then we are done, so we assume $R<S$. Then we have to show that 
$4(S-R)\le Q$. Since $Q>S^2/R$, it suffices to show that $4(S-R)\le S^2/R$, that is 
$0\le (S-2R)^2$.

Comment: In equation (1), shouldn't it be "$+Q$" on the RHS? In $P$, $-(2S-Q)=-2S+Q$.

Comment: Oops. Thanks. I'll correct this.

Comment: @durdi Corrected.